# How to calculate membership retention rate in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Membership table with with Start_Date and End_Date.
I have created a Date table and mapped Date to Start_Date.
I have a Date slicer

How can I calculate membership retention rate for the selected year?

I tried below DAX query which is not returning any value.

Download Pbix file here : [PowerBi File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oVoF3gECgsLQ0z6KOXmyURWyLfPJBNF0/view?usp=sharing)

Kindly help with the correct DAX query

```
RR = 
VAR SelectedYear = SELECTEDVALUE('Date'[Year])
RETURN
CALCULATE(
DIVIDE(
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            Membership,
            Membership[End_Date] >= DATE(SelectedYear, 1, 1) 
            && Membership[End_Date] < DATE(SelectedYear + 1, 1, 1)
        )
    ),
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            Membership,
            Membership[Start_Date] < DATE(SelectedYear, 1, 1)
            && (
                Membership[End_Date] >= DATE(SelectedYear, 1, 1) 
                || ISBLANK(Membership[End_Date])
            )
        )
    )
), USERELATIONSHIP('Date'[Date],MEMBERSHIP[START_DATE]))
```

I tried above query and didn't find any use. Also tried below query for 2022 retention rate. But, not sure whether it is correct?

```
Retention Rate 2022 = 
DIVIDE(
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            'MEMBERSHIP',
            'MEMBERSHIP'[END_DATE]>= DATE(2022,1,1) 
            && 'MEMBERSHIP'[END_DATE] < DATE(2023,1,1)
        )
    ),
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            'MEMBERSHIP',
            'MEMBERSHIP'[START_DATE]< DATE(2022,1,1)
            && (
                'MEMBERSHIP'[END_DATE] >= DATE(2022,1,1) 
                || ISBLANK('MEMBERSHIP'[END_DATE])
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the filter in your calculate to ALL('Date') - basically you want to ignore any filters on membership start date, to consider the whole universe of members, and then apply the filters on either date fields, like you are already doing:

```
RR = 
VAR SelectedYear = SELECTEDVALUE('Date'[Year])
RETURN
CALCULATE(
DIVIDE(
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            Membership,
            Membership[End_Date] >= DATE(SelectedYear, 1, 1) 
            && Membership[End_Date] < DATE(SelectedYear + 1, 1, 1)
        )
    ),
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            Membership,
            Membership[Start_Date] < DATE(SelectedYear, 1, 1)
            && (
                Membership[End_Date] >= DATE(SelectedYear, 1, 1) 
                || ISBLANK(Membership[End_Date])
            )
        )
    )
), ALL('Date'))
```